# C# Newtonsoft.Json JObject naming convention

Tags: c#, json.net, naming-conventions

I have a question about naming conventions. I am using Newtonsoft.Json to create JObjects and also have other non-json structs and classes. What is a good naming convention for these? Eg

```
var objectJson = new JObject();
var myObject = new Object();
var myClass = new MyClass();
```

I would like to differentiate between the two.. Welcome all suggestions. 
PS - I am aware this question does not have definite answers but would still like some opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [coding standards](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards) and you will figure out yourself what is the best naming for your variables.